# Is find possible to get out a file name based on the lates date?

Tags: find

Is `find` possible to use `-name` parameter as this type `$(date +%Y%m%d%H)`? I want to find a file named based on the latest date. The example as below:
Wish a kind feedback.

1. 2017101309
2. 2017101310

Comment: Does `find . -name "$(date +%Y%m%d%H)"` not do what you want?

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas `sudo find . -name "$(date %Y%m%d%H)" -exec rm -rf {} \;` this command have a result for my wanted. The file is still there.

Comment: What file? Is it a file whose name is equal to the expansion of `"$(date +%Y%m%d%H)"` and that is in the current working directory or one of its subdirectories?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Hi, it is my typo. I miss `+`. Really appreciate your help and patient with this trivia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right, you have files that are named by the date that they are created.  Just try supplying `$(date +%Y%m%d%H)` as the parameter after `-name`.  Like this:

```
find . -name "$(date +%Y%m%d%H)"
```